# Delete lines starting with pattern from a file

Tags: command-line, bash, regex

I tried several commands: `tr`, `sed` but to no avail. Here's the file:

```
> ...
> ...
> setEPS()
> postscript('images/boxplot_default.eps')
> ...
> ...
```

I want to delete those two undotted lines. Something simple like `/> setEps\(\)\n/` would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally got it: use `perl`!

```
perl -i -p -e 's/> setEPS\(\)\n//g' filename
```

so, the final command:

```
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/\> setEPS\(\)\n\> postscript\([^\n]*\n\> \n//g' ${output}
```